# Checkboxes are not working in python web.py

Tags: python, checkbox, web.py

I am using web.py framework for creating small web pages.I had a basic html that has a form with four checkbox fields as below

**home.html**

```
$def with ( )
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <form method="POST" action="/checkboxes">
      <p>check_1     <input type="checkbox" id="curly_1" value="" name="curly_1"/></p>
      <p>check_2     <input type="checkbox" id="curly_2" value="" name="curly_2"/></p>  
      <p>check_3     <input type="checkbox" id="curly_3" value="" name="curly_3"/></p>  
      <p>check_4     <input type="checkbox" id="curly_4" value="" name="curly_4"/></p>      
      <button id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**index.py**

```
import os
import sys
import web
from web import form

render = web.template.render('templates/')


urls = (
  '/checkboxes',   'Checkboxes',  
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class Checkboxes:

    def POST(self):
        i = web.input(groups = {})
        print i,">>>>>>>>>>>>"
        raise web.seeother('/checkboxes')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    web.internalerror = web.debugerror
    app.run()
```

**Result:**

```
<Storage {'curly_3': u'', 'submit': u'', 'curly_4': u'', 'curly_1': u'', 'groups': [], 'curly_2': u''}> >>>>>>>>>>>>
```

So from the html view i can see four `checkbox` fields, i had checked all checkboxes and clicked the submit button, now it should come to `Checkboxes` class and should print the result of the input(checkboxes that are checked) in post method as i had shown above.

But in result i am getting empty string(No result) as shown above,

can anyone please let me know whats wrong in the above code

Also how to get the values of checkboxes that are selected ?

Answer (score 1):

The presence of a checkbox element's name in the dictionary returned by web.input() indicates the field was checked. Otherwise, it won't be present in the dictionary. Try checking a subset of the four checkboxes on your form and I think you'll see what I mean.

More details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/webpy/checkbox/webpy/PVBdPv7kGDM/IqgLptUEN-EJ

Comment: :Thanks for ur reply, what i want is it should display a vaue of TRUE or FALSE based on whether it is checked or not. How can we achieve this ?

Comment: You can obtain the equivalent of an explicit True or False value by checking existence of any given checkbox in the dictionary returned by web.input(). For example, instead of looking to see if curly_1 is checked like this:

    if i['curly_1']:

which won't work because curly_1 will be present only when checked, you could use logic like this:

    if 'curly_1' in i:

because the desired key will only be present in the returned dictionary if the corresponding checkbox was checked.

Comment: yes of course,but somewhere i had seen getting those values(True or False),so asked about how we can get True or False values when clicked the check box?is there any some other way of getting the values as True or False,because i am designing a page that displays all the records from database,now user can select some  appropriate records by checking the checkbox and will click retrieve button(that creates a csv file with only records that are checked).So what i am trying is when the user select the record by checking it,i can check the values of the records that are true and will retrieve that

Comment: I don't understand -- if you simply want true/false values, you could create another dictionary with the same set of keys mapped to boolean values indicating checked/unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

If you need simply all checkbox value as checked or unchecked, you can handle its like a ajax call. For this change input type submit to button. Then take all input check boxes checked or not and fill its values into json. Then its value rtrieve your controller post method.

Comment: :can you please provide me an ajax example code based from the above scenario ?, so that i can learn practically good(i don't know ajax actually :))

Comment: $("#submit").click(function(){
var curl1_val = $('input[name=curly_1]').is(':checked');
var curl2_val = $('input[name=curly_2]').is(':checked');
var curl3_val = $('input[name=curly_3]').is(':checked');
var curl4_val = $('input[name=curly_4]').is(':checked');
$.ajax({
url: '/checkboxes',                                                     type:'POST',
data:{action:'checkboxes',curly_1:curl1_val,curly_2:curl2_val,curly_3:curl3_val,curly_4:curl4_val},
success: function(data){
},
error:function(data){
alert("error"+data);
}
}); 
}); 


             You should get these value by using web.input().